# JavaScript IE read data from json file Access Denied

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax, internet-explorer

I have problem with my code on IE browser  and Chrome in FireFox all works well done.

```
var currentPage = 1;
var max = 0;
var myList = [];
var links = [];  

    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type : 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType : 'json',
        url: 'list.json',
        success : function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, value){
                if(window.location.href == value.link){
                    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = value.page;
                    currentPage = value.page;
                }
                document.getElementById("countAll").innerHTML = value.page;
                myList.push("<li><a href=" + value.link +"><b>"+value.page+"</b></a></li>");
                max = value.page;
                links.push(value.link);
                })
            $('.pagination').html(myList.join(''));
            if ( currentPage == 0){
                document.getElementById("leftArrow").innerHTML = "&#10096;"
                document.getElementById("rightArrow").innerHTML = "<a href="+links[currentPage]+">&#10097;</a>";
            } else if (currentPage == max){
                document.getElementById("leftArrow").innerHTML = "<a href="+links[currentPage-2]+">&#10096;</a>";
                document.getElementById("rightArrow").innerHTML = "&#10097;"
            } else {
                document.getElementById("leftArrow").innerHTML = "<a href="+links[currentPage-2]+">&#10096;</a>";
                document.getElementById("rightArrow").innerHTML = "<a href="+links[currentPage]+">&#10097;</a>";
            }
        }
    }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(errorThrown); });
```

In IE I have err: "Access Denied", anyone know this problem? Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use the crossDomain attribute since the url you are accessing is local?

```
 $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type : 'GET',
        crossDomain: true // <--- cross domain
```

In case you really need to do cross domain calls maybe you should try this jQuery plugin for IE:

https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest